# Openwrt: Sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d09fec

Tags: segmentation-fault, rpc, openwrt, luci

`openwrt version - 21.02 and 22.03`

`luci2 web interface is ported to openwrt from the github link - https://github.com/mvaello/luci2 (luci2-2014-07-06-ef48c52)`

```
rpcd (default version)
rpcd-2022-02-07-909f2a04
PKG_MIRROR_HASH:=186a7246c610fecc282b0966213350ff4508b0db88739345e7c79792db0423ce
PKG_SOURCE_DATE:=2022-02-07
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=909f2a04763dbc745488384b24281eca180452d6
```

I'm unable to login to webpage even after giving correct password. In dmesg, I got `rpcd segfault` logs. `rpcd` gives no error without `luci2`. But, I got the below logs in dmesg after installing `luci2`.

```
[   18.498368] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d09fec
[   18.514714] epc = 5556984b in rpcd[55560000+b000]
[   18.524179] ra  = 55569839 in rpcd[55560000+b000]
[   23.556422] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d74fec
[   23.572784] epc = 5563984b in rpcd[55630000+b000]
[   23.582220] ra  = 55639839 in rpcd[55630000+b000]
[   28.616680] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d20fec
[   28.633042] epc = 555c984b in rpcd[555c0000+b000]
[   28.642470] ra  = 555c9839 in rpcd[555c0000+b000]
[   33.676557] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d10fec
[   33.692915] epc = 5555984b in rpcd[55550000+b000]
[   33.702338] ra  = 55559839 in rpcd[55550000+b000]
[   38.736472] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77ceefec
[   38.752835] epc = 5562984b in rpcd[55620000+b000]
[   38.762260] ra  = 55629839 in rpcd[55620000+b000]
```

```
root@OpenWrt:/# rpcd 
[  802.940186] do_page_fault(): sending SIGSEGV to rpcd for invalid write access to 77d71fec
[  802.956490] epc = 5562984b in rpcd[55620000+b000]
[  802.965913] ra  = 55629839 in rpcd[55620000+b000]
Segmentation fault
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is something related to memory. Are you sure you have enough free space in RAM?

If you are a developer, I think you should enable coredump / increase log level for kernel dump to debug for this